Como añadir Css al elemento HTML details y summary
Tengo el siguiente código que me muestra un listado a través de los elementos details y sumary. El css es externo.


<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<details>
  <summary>Listado</summary>
  <p>Listado de productos</p>
  <p>Listado de productos 2</p>
  <p>Listado de productos 3</p>
</details>



El caso es que Listado que aparece dentro de summary me lo muestra más pequeño que lo que me muestra el listado de productos de la etiqueta p. Hay un conflicto con el css interno y el summary lo muestra en un tamaño menor. ¿Como podría hacer la llamda de css al elemento summary para que me muestre el tamaño de la fuente normal como esta en los listados de los productos.?

Puedes compartir tu css para echarle un ojo también? Puedes añadirlo editando la pregunta original.

Te comento, en CSS3 hay una forma sencilla de hacer lo que pides, seria algo asi:
elementoPadre elementoHijo{
    estilos
}

Para tu caso concreto, podrias hacer algo asi:
details summary{
  font-size: inherit;
}

De esta manera estaras aplicando los estilos a todos los elementos summary (hijo) dentro del elemento details (padre).
Ojo, esto puede ser un problema o una ventaja, en tu caso, solamente tienes un elemento summary dentro de details, pero imagina esta situacion:
<style>
  div h1{
    color: blue;
  }
</style>



<div>
  <h1>Primer h1</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <h1>Segundo h1</h1>
</div>

En este caso, estariamos aplicando el color azul a todos los h1 dentro del div, a si que debes tener esto en cuenta para situaciones futuras.
Un saludo, cualquier pregunta al respecto dejala por los comentarios!

Gracias por tu aporte. El caso es que si lo hago en un archivo individual externo, por ejemplo en local, todo ok. El problema que tengo es que si lo coloco ya en la web, no funciona. El css que tengo es externo y por tanto no lo puedo controlar. No se si lo podré solucionar. No obstante he estado revisando y la fuente es algo más pequeña, pero no imposibilita una buena visualización para móviles.

Disculpa la tardanza, prueba a poner una etiqueta style dentro de tu html y agregale al final de cada linea css el parametro !important, que quede algo del tipo -> color: blue !important;

Gracias Roberto. Estuve haciendo prueba de visualización para móviles y son correctas, por lo que no necesito modificación. No obstante te agradezco tu tiempo. Hace tiempo tuve otro problema con codigo css y ese código lo ponía directamente en el código del enlace y todo ok style="color: white; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal;"
